# Prove this relation for all polynomials by inductive.

Tags: polynomials, induction, roots

We know $P(x) = ax^n + bx^{n-1} + cx^{n-2} + ... + z = 0$ .

also $ \alpha , \beta , \gamma$ and ... $\omega $ are roots of $P(x)$.

in the other hand :

$S_n = \alpha^n + \beta^n + \gamma^n + ...+ \omega^n $ , $S_{n-1} = \alpha^{n-1} + \beta^{n-1} + \gamma^{n-1} + ...+ \omega^{n-1} $ and so on.

How we can prove this relation by induction ?

$aS_n + bS_{n-1} + cS_{n-2} + .... + zS_0 = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear how to use the induction and in fact we don’t need it, becuse we can proof the claim directly. For the simplicity we denote the polynomial $$P(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots a_n x^n$$ and its roots as $$\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n.$$ Then for each $i$ $$S_i=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j^i.$$ If we additionally put $S_0=n$ we obtain

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_iS_i=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j^i=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \alpha_j^i 
=\sum_{j=1}^n P(\alpha_j)= \sum_{j=1}^n 0=0.$$

PS. We have to have $nz$ instead of $z$ in the initial formulation of your question.

Comment: should be $P(\alpha_j)$ not $P(\alpha_j^i)$

Comment: @Anonymous Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Your answer is very good and complete but is there any way to prove it by induction ?

Comment: @S.H.W The only parameter which look suitable for the induction is the degree $n$ of the polynomial $P(x)$. Unfortunately, I see no natural or obvious way to relate its  roots with roots of some polynomial of degree $n-1$ with easily written coefficients. Maybe somebody other can do it.

Comment: You said we have to have $nz$ instead of $z$. why ?

Comment: @S.H.W When we transform $\sum_{j=1}^n P(\alpha_j)$ to $\sum_{i=0}^n a_iS_i$, $nz$ corresponds to the sum $\sum_{j=1}^n a_0\alpha_j^0\equiv \sum_{j=1}^n a_0=n a_0=nz$. So the sum which is expected in the question to be zero is in fact $(1-n)z$.

Comment: Thank you a lot but I have another question. Do you know any sources that indicate transformations of sigma and proof of them ? I have problem to understand transformations of sigma in your answer. Thanks again.